# laTex cv currvita

Tags: templates, latex, resume

I found this template and I would like to modify two things but all I tried does not work:

- I would like to have more white vertical space before it displays my name since it's too close to the top as it is now
- I would like the text of experience (blablablablabla..) to be more wide and therefore to reduce left and right margins

Any ideas on how to modify this template?
Thx

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Classicthesis-Styled CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (22/2/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Alessandro Plasmati
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\hspace{3.5cm}\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.3em}} % Add some white space after each new entry 

% 
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\date{} % Don't print the date
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Mario Rossi}}\vspace{1.8em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Contact Information}
\vspace{0.1em}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{Address}{Salita del carro, L'isola che non c'è} % Address


\NewEntry{Email}{\href{mailto:name@gmail.com}{name@gmail.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{Linkedin}{\href{http://it.linkedin.com/pub/....}{http://it.linkedin.com/...../}} % Linkedin

\NewEntry{Phone}{+39 333\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ 11111111} % Phone number


%\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal
%\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

%\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{0.6em}% Extra space between major sections
\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Experience}
\vspace{0.1em}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}
%------------------------------------------------


\NewEntry{}{ \textsc{Somewhere,\textit{ City} }}

\Description{\MarginText{July - December 2015}blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla\\ }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I addressed your two requirements:

1. Insert an invisible, vertical strut as part of the `\cvheadingfont`. I used `\rule{0pt}{100pt}`, but you can adjust (increase/decrease) the value of `100pt` to move the content up/down.
2. Switched the document class to use the default `article` class, since there seems to be no need for using [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). This also allows for ease-of-use when changing the page layout/geometry using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). You can adjust the `left` and `right` margins to suit your needs.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Classicthesis-Styled CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (22/2/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Alessandro Plasmati
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{article}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{%
  \rule{0pt}{100pt}%
  \centering\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{%
  \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
  \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here:
    % #1 is the left margin,
    % #2 is the italic date field and
    % #3 is the position/employer/location field
  \vspace{0.3em}} % Add some white space after each new entry 

% 
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{%
  \hangindent=1em\hangafter=0
  \noindent\raggedright\footnotesize #1\par
  \normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here


\usepackage[left=100pt,right=2cm]{geometry}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\date{} % Don't print the date
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Mario Rossi}}\vspace{1.8em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Contact Information}
\vspace{0.1em}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{Address}{Salita del carro, L'isola che non c'è} % Address

\NewEntry{Email}{\href{mailto:name@gmail.com}{name@gmail.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{Linkedin}{\href{http://it.linkedin.com/pub/....}{http://it.linkedin.com/...../}} % Linkedin

\NewEntry{Phone}{+39 333\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ 11111111} % Phone number


%\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal
%\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

%\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{0.6em}% Extra space between major sections
\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Experience}
\vspace{0.1em}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}
%------------------------------------------------


\NewEntry{}{\textsc{Somewhere,\textit{City}}}

\Description{\MarginText{July - December 2015}\lipsum[1]}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```